# Using datetime or timestamp with basic webpy blog

Tags: python, datetime, psql, web.py

I have been following this basic blog setup with Webpy:

http://webpy.org/src/blog/0.3

I have everything exactly the same so I dont think any need for me to post my code here, however I am using Psql and thus I had to make a few changes to my model.py which is as follows:

```
import web
import datetime

db = web.database(dbn="postgres", db='basic_blog', user='my_name')

def get_posts():
    return db.select('entries', order='id DESC')

def get_post(id):
    try:
        return db.select('entries', where='id=$id', vars=locals())[0]
    except IndexError:
        return None

def new_post(title, text):
    db.insert('entries', title=title, content=text, posted_on=timestamp)

def del_post(id):
    db.insert('entries', where='id=$id', vars=locals())

def update_post(id, title, text):
    db.update('entries', where='id=$id', vars=locals(),
        title=title, content=text)
```

when I created the schema I was not able to use DATETIME as it doesn't seem to be in psql so I used TIMESTAMP instead, however I am unsure how to get this to work in the model.py file or if I need to import datetime still.

When I try to run it as is above and go to /new in my local host I get this error message:

```
global name 'timestamp' is not defined
```

I have tried changing the type in the psql schema to just 'date' but still got the same problems and not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timestamp in your argument is a variable that you need to define.

```
def new_post(title, text):
    db.insert('entries', title=title, content=text, posted_on=timestamp)
```

so instead:

```
import datetime
```

you can:

```
import time
```

and in your new_post function, generate a new timestamp when the function being called:

```
def new_post(title, text):
    timestamp = time.time() # define the variable: timestamp
    db.insert('entries', title=title, content=text, posted_on=timestamp)
```

Note: `time.time()` return a `float` object which can represent milliseconds, but if you don't care about milliseconds, you can use `int(time.time())` instead.

Comment: so Im getting this error now as soon as I hit submit after writing a test post  <class 'psycopg2.ProgrammingError'> at /new
column "posted_on" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type numeric LINE 1: ...tries (content, posted_on, title) VALUES ('test', 1450833444... ^ HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/db.py in _db_execute, line 586
Web POST http://localhost:8080/new

Comment: 'test' is the test post I was trying to submit there, Im not sure what expression I need to rewrite, does it mean an expression in psql? Ive been reading the docs about timestamp and from what I understand just doing 'posted_on TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE' should work (I think)

Comment: Ive changed to mysql so everything is setup exactly like the example-tutorial now but getting this error now instead when trying to submit a new post:                                                                                                             '<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> at /
can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware date times'                                             why is this so complex just to submit a basic post on a simple blog? :/

Comment: I think you better restart the process:  

   1. use mysql as database, and the default attr of column `posted_on` should be DATETIME.  

   2. use webpy db back end and change dbn to `mysql`, like: `db = web.database(dbn='mysql', user='username', pw='password', db='dbname')`  

   3. use default script as the link you posted: `posted_on=datetime.datetime.utcnow()`  
  
   and see what would happen

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with psql. but I think the problem is at "psql support TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE attribute which mysql don't", and you mix two kind of data types together.

good luck!